# How do you determine a measure function based on this recursive function?

Tags: functional-programming, logic, acl

A function is defined in ACL2, and we are tasked with creating a measure function to help prove termination. This is the function definition:

```
(defunc f (x a)
  :input-contract (and (integerp x) (listp a))
  :output-contract (integerp (f x a))
  (cond
   ((endp a)                 68)
   ((equal (len a) x)        71)
   ((equal (len a) (+ x 1))  74)
   ((< x (len a))            (f (+ x 1) (rest a)))
   (t                        (f (- x 1) (cons 1 a)))))
```

And a solution measure function is this (in shorthand):

```
(m x a) = (if (equal (len a) (+ x 1))
              0
              (abs (- (len a) x)))
```

We were able to determine the else case of the measure function would be included, based on the two recursive calls in the function. However, we don't understand the rest of it, and the process that went into figuring out this measure function.

For reference, a measure function:

1. m is an admissible function deﬁned over the parameters of f;
2. m has the same input contract as f;
3. m has an output contract stating that it always returns a natural number; and
4. on every recursive call, m applied to the arguments to that recursive call decreases,
   under the conditions that led to the recursive call.

What is the process that led to determining this measure function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When determining a measure function, the question to ask yourself is: What is the "potential energy" that gets used up on each iteration, to the point where at some point it's all gone and the iteration stops?

The first place to look is usually the termination conditions. In this case there are three, but the last two are the most interesting: they say we stop iterating if the difference between `x` and `(len a)` is too small.

That gives us an idea: what if the potential energy is difference between `(len a)` and `x`? To see whether that makes sense, we need to check the recursive cases and make sure that each one of them uses up some energy, i.e. decreases the difference. Things look pretty good here:

- If `x` is less than `(len a)` we increase `x` by 1 and decrease `(len a)` by 1. So if the difference between them was *n*, then on the next iteration it will be *n-2* unless *x = `(len a)` - 1*.
- Otherwise `x` is greater than `(len a)` and we decrease `x` by 1 and increase `(len a)` by 1. Again, if the difference between them was *n*, then on the next iteration it will be *n-2* unless *x = `(len a)` + 1*.

From there it's pretty easy to see that we should choose *x = `(len a)` + 1* as our "low energy state", since it handles the pesky detail of those two *unless* clauses.